# How can I automatically register services in .net core dependency injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-core

My team is looking at converting our solution to .net core and we are trying to decide whether we should stick with StructureMap as our DI tool or use Microsoft's one that is provided with .net core. One thing we have with StructureMap is the ability to automatically register our services based on naming conventions (something like this):

```
Scan(s =>
{
    s.WithDefaultConventions();
    s.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(AssemblyFilter);
});
```

Is there a way to do this with Microsoft's DI container out of the box?

Comment: No. But you should be able to plug in structure map into the core DI structure.

Comment: Check repo https://github.com/structuremap/StructureMap.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: Do take note of the suggestion to move over to Lamar since StructureMap has been shuttered.

Comment: @Nkosi Yeah I'm aware of the fact that StructureMap is not actively being worked on anymore which is exactly why we would like to use the built in Microsoft one.

Comment: This is not supported currently. You have to write your own scanner :/